# Laravel Как передать relation в роуты с определенным префиксом

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование, blade

У меня в `RouteServiceProvider` определен префикс

```
Route::prefix('admin-menu')
  ->middleware( 'web')
  ->namespace($this->adminNamespace)
  ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
```

Папка для контроллеров - Admin
Мне нужно чтобы в каждом контроллере (отвечает за определенную страницу в админке) - можно было достучаться до `auth()->user()->settings`, `settings - relation (UserSettings table)`

Как это правильно сделать, чтобы можно было вывести натсройки в админке и каждый раз не передавать их в контроллере на вьюху ?

Comment: А при чем здесь префиксы? Для доступа к auth() нужно прописать ['auth'](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) middleware для роута. Префиксы используются для другого.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да, вот только как передать эти данные в контроллер? Middleware предназначен для другого а не для передачи данных

Comment: Этот метод [глобально доступен](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) внутри фреймворка через auth(), либо Auth фасад. Извлекаете через него пользователя, а у него будет доступ к настройкам.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov ну вот по этому я и не хочу каждый раз через auth() доставать юзера а тогда еще доставать сетинги